# Could not find function "%<>%" with dplyr loaded

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe

[Disclaimer: similar questions have been asked many times. I don't believe this is the same as the many threads I've just read.]

I did:

```
library(dplyr)
colnames(LarvalSamples) %<>% 
  stringr::str_remove_all("_log") %>% 
  stringr::str_replace_all("Sea_Level", "Sea_Level_Height") %>% #sealevel, sealion, chinook, chl
  stringr::str_replace_all("SeaLion", "Sea_lion") %>% 
  stringr::str_replace_all("Chinook_Salmon", "Salmon") %>% 
  stringr::str_replace_all("Chlorophyll_a", "Chlorophyll_A")
```

Worked fine, no messages, outputs as expected/desired. Then I copy/pasted those first two lines, except the terminal pipe:

```
colnames(LarvalSamples) %<>%
  stringr::str_remove_all("_log")
```

> Error in colnames(LarvalSamples) %<>% stringr::str_remove_all("_log")
>   :    could not find function "%<>%"

I realise there are other posts on here about not finding functions but `dplyr` is loaded AND worked on MORE code just two lines above. As it happens there are no `"_log"` patterns in the `colnames` but I tried a different character pattern which does exist and that failed the same so that's one potential source of error eliminated. Any thoughts/guesses appreciated, this feels like a bug more than a question tbh but would be good to get sharper eyes on it before raising it up the chain, if so required. Thanks.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.8.0.1  beepr_1.3      gbm.auto_1.2.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.0       compiler_3.5.0   pillar_1.3.1     shapefiles_0.7   tools_3.5.0      tibble_2.0.1    
 [7] gtable_0.2.0     lattice_0.20-35  pkgconfig_2.0.2  rlang_0.3.1      Matrix_1.2-14    DBI_1.0.0       
[13] rstudioapi_0.9.0 rgdal_1.4-2      gbm_2.1.5        dismo_1.1-4      gridExtra_2.3    stringr_1.4.0   
[19] raster_2.8-19    mapplots_1.5.1   rgeos_0.4-2      grid_3.5.0       tidyselect_0.2.5 glue_1.3.0      
[25] R6_2.4.0         survival_2.41-3  foreign_0.8-70   sp_1.3-1         purrr_0.3.1      magrittr_1.5    
[31] codetools_0.2-15 splines_3.5.0    maptools_0.9-5   assertthat_0.2.0 stringi_1.3.1    crayon_1.3.4    
[37] audio_0.1-5.1
```

Update: Reproducible example below. This definitely seems to be a bug. With a completely fresh system:

```
Data <- data.frame(
    Name_Bad = sample(1:10),
    Name_Guud = sample(1:10)
  )

  colnames(Data) %<>%
    stringr::str_remove_all("_Bad") %>%
    stringr::str_replace_all("Guud", "Good")
  # Error: could not find function "%>%"

  install.packages("dplyr")
  library(dplyr)
  install.packages("stringr")
  library(stringr)

  colnames(Data) %<>%
    stringr::str_remove_all("_Bad") %>%
    stringr::str_replace_all("Guud", "Good")
# no error, worked

  colnames(Data) %<>%
    stringr::str_remove_all("_Bad")
  # Error: could not find function "%<>%"
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`%<>%` isn’t exported by dplyr (only `%>%` is). You need to load magrittr instead.

Your reproducible example is running into [a subtle magrittr bug](https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr/issues/194), which causes the evaluation of pipeline expressions to search for some operators in magrittr’s scope, rather than in the calling scope. That way, `x %<>% y %>% z`, which evaluates as `` `%>%`(x %<>% y, z) ``, finds and evaluates magrittr’s `` `%<>%` `` operator.

Comment: Thanks; accepted as answer but the underlying peculiarity / unintuitive behaviour remains: why did it work in a longer pipeline but not for a single command? If it had failed for the first call then I would have known to delve deeper...

Comment: @dez93_2000 It never worked in the longer pipeline for the code you’ve shown (you can easily verify this by executing that command again). Instead, when you executed the longer code you had (for some reason) previously loaded magrittr in the active session.

Comment: Konrad I can promise you 100% that it did indeed work for the longer code, and that I changed nothing (in terms of loading/unloading packages) between the two code line executions. At no point until your answer did I explicitly load magrittr. I've got to try to get a paper submitted today but once I've done this main modelling run I'll try to circle back to this and make a neat reproducible example. Cheers again for your help.

Comment: Konrad, hi again, reproducible example added, appears to be a bug.

Comment: @dez93_2000 Amazing, thanks for your persistence. You’re right, this is a fiendish bug due to how `%>%` scopes its arguments for evaluation. I’ll edit my answer to explain why. It might also be worth to report this bug although I doubt it will be fixed.

Comment: Certainly a weird one. Thanks for raising the bug. And hey, you never know, I feel 2019 is going to be a great year :)

Answer (score 0):

Command `%>%View()` preventing subsequent command execution.

I had the same problem with the same error message.
Even if I installed the `dplyr` library the message appeared. I didn't check conflict between package with homonym command.

I noticed that in my code there was a data.frame `df1` using the pipe operator followed by the command `View()`, then that same data.frame `df1` was used in calling another data.frame `df2`, so it was impossible for the `df2` data.frame to be executed because of the `%>%View()` command.

Error script:

```
df1%>%
  filter(var1='X')%>%
  View()

df2<-df1%>%
  mutate(var2=var1*2)
```

Script free-error:

```
df1%>%
  filter(var1='X')

df2<-df1%>%
  mutate(var2=var1*2)
```

What I notice is that because of the `View()` command in `df1`  it doesn't produce an executable result in `df2`.